# AttributeError: 'MeshPlotter' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following script, which uses Tkinter.

```
class MeshPlotter(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, filename):
        super().__init__(self, parent)

        self.labels = {
            'Cell': 'Cell:',
            'Cellborn': 'Cell born:',
            'Surface': 'Surface:',
            'Material': 'Material:',
            'Universe': 'Universe:',
            'Energy': 'Energy in:',
            'Energyout': 'Energy out:'
        }

        self.filterBoxes = {}

        # Read data from source or leakage fraction file
        self.get_file_data(filename)

        # Set up top-level window
        top = self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.title('Mesh Tally Plotter: ' + filename)
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.W+tk.N)

        # Create widgets and draw to screen
        self.create_widgets()
        self.update()
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
app = MeshPlotter(root, filename)
.
.
.
self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'MeshPlotter' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Complete Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/daniel/.local/bin/openmc-plot-mesh-tally", line 327, in <module>
app = MeshPlotter(root, filename)
File "/home/daniel/.local/bin/openmc-plot-mesh-tally", line 29, in __init__
super(MeshPlotter, self).__init__(self, parent)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2744, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2262, in _setup
self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'MeshPlotter' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: what is your `import` code?

Comment: Please show the complete error

Comment: What is `master`? If `master` is the parent window `root` then why you have `parent` as a parameter when you are using `master`?

Comment: Why did you do master.tk ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My import code is:
import os
import sys
import argparse
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from openmc import StatePoint, MeshFilter

Comment: `super().__init__(self, parent)` should be `super().__init__(parent)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please the complete error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/daniel/.local/bin/openmc-plot-mesh-tally", line 327, in <module>
app = MeshPlotter(root, filename)
File "/home/daniel/.local/bin/openmc-plot-mesh-tally", line 29, in __init__
super(MeshPlotter, self).__init__(self, parent)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2744, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2262, in _setup
self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'MeshPlotter' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

The complete code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""Python script to plot tally data generated by OpenMC."""

import os
import sys
import argparse
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from openmc import StatePoint, MeshFilter

_COMBOBOX_SELECTED = '<<ComboboxSelected>>'


class MeshPlotter(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, filename):
    super().__init__(self, parent)

    self.labels = {
        'Cell': 'Cell:',
        'Cellborn': 'Cell born:',
        'Surface': 'Surface:',
        'Material': 'Material:',
        'Universe': 'Universe:',
        'Energy': 'Energy in:',
        'Energyout': 'Energy out:'
    }

    self.filterBoxes = {}

    # Read data from source or leakage fraction file
    self.get_file_data(filename)

    # Set up top-level window
    top = self.winfo_toplevel()
    top.title('Mesh Tally Plotter: ' + filename)
    top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid(sticky=tk.W+tk.N)

    # Create widgets and draw to screen
    self.create_widgets()
    self.update()

def create_widgets(self):
    figureFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    figureFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Create the Figure and Canvas
    self.dpi = 100
    self.fig = Figure((5.0, 5.0), dpi=self.dpi)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=figureFrame)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    # Create the navigation toolbar, tied to the canvas
    self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, figureFrame)
    self.mpl_toolbar.update()
    self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    # Create frame for comboboxes
    self.selectFrame = tk.Frame(self)
    self.selectFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

    # Tally selection
    labelTally = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text='Tally:')
    labelTally.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    self.tallyBox = ttk.Combobox(self.selectFrame, state='readonly')
    self.tallyBox['values'] = [self.datafile.tallies[i].id
                               for i in self.meshTallies]
    self.tallyBox.current(0)
    self.tallyBox.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    self.tallyBox.bind(_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, self.update)

    # Planar basis selection
    labelBasis = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text='Basis:')
    labelBasis.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    self.basisBox = ttk.Combobox(self.selectFrame, state='readonly')
    self.basisBox['values'] = ('xy', 'yz', 'xz')
    self.basisBox.current(0)
    self.basisBox.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    self.basisBox.bind(_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, self.update)

    # Axial level
    labelAxial = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text='Axial level:')
    labelAxial.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    self.axialBox = ttk.Combobox(self.selectFrame, state='readonly')
    self.axialBox.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    self.axialBox.bind(_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, self.redraw)

    # Option for mean/uncertainty
    labelMean = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text='Mean/Uncertainty:')
    labelMean.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    self.meanBox = ttk.Combobox(self.selectFrame, state='readonly')
    self.meanBox['values'] = ('Mean', 'Absolute uncertainty',
                              'Relative uncertainty')
    self.meanBox.current(0)
    self.meanBox.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    self.meanBox.bind(_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, self.update)

    # Scores
    labelScore = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text='Score:')
    labelScore.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    self.scoreBox = ttk.Combobox(self.selectFrame, state='readonly')
    self.scoreBox.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
    self.scoreBox.bind(_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, self.redraw)

    # Filter label
    boldfont = font.Font(weight='bold')
    labelFilters = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text='Filters:',
                            font=boldfont)
    labelFilters.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

def update(self, event=None):
    widget = event.widget if event else None

    tally_id = self.meshTallies[self.tallyBox.current()]
    selectedTally = self.datafile.tallies[tally_id]

    # Get mesh for selected tally
    self.mesh = selectedTally.find_filter(MeshFilter).mesh

    # Get mesh dimensions
    if len(self.mesh.dimension) == 2:
        self.nx, self.ny = self.mesh.dimension
        self.nz = 1
    else:
        self.nx, self.ny, self.nz = self.mesh.dimension

    # Repopulate comboboxes baesd on current basis selection
    text = self.basisBox.get()
    if text == 'xy':
        self.axialBox['values'] = [str(i+1) for i in range(self.nz)]
    elif text == 'yz':
        self.axialBox['values'] = [str(i+1) for i in range(self.nx)]
    else:
        self.axialBox['values'] = [str(i+1) for i in range(self.ny)]
    self.axialBox.current(0)

    # If update() was called by a change in the basis combobox, we don't
    # need to repopulate the filters
    if widget == self.basisBox:
        self.redraw()
        return

    # Update scores
    self.scoreBox['values'] = selectedTally.scores
    self.scoreBox.current(0)

    # Remove any filter labels/comboboxes that exist
    for row in range(6, self.selectFrame.grid_size()[1]):
        for w in self.selectFrame.grid_slaves(row=row):
            w.grid_forget()
            w.destroy()

    # create a label/combobox for each filter in selected tally
    count = 0
    for f in selectedTally.filters:
        filterType = f.short_name
        if filterType == 'Mesh':
            continue
        count += 1

        # Create label and combobox for this filter
        label = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text=self.labels[filterType])
        label.grid(row=count+6, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.selectFrame, state='readonly')
        self.filterBoxes[filterType] = combobox

        # Set combobox items
        if filterType in ['Energy', 'Energyout']:
            combobox['values'] = ['{} to {}'.format(*ebin)
                                  for ebin in f.bins]
        else:
            combobox['values'] = [str(i) for i in f.bins]

        combobox.current(0)
        combobox.grid(row=count+6, column=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
        combobox.bind(_COMBOBOX_SELECTED, self.redraw)

    # If There are no filters, leave a 'None available' message
    if count == 0:
        count += 1
        label = tk.Label(self.selectFrame, text="None Available")
        label.grid(row=count+6, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

    self.redraw()

def redraw(self, event=None):
    basis = self.basisBox.current() + 1
    axial_level = self.axialBox.current() + 1
    mbvalue = self.meanBox.get()

    # Get selected tally
    tally_id = self.meshTallies[self.tallyBox.current()]
    selectedTally = self.datafile.tallies[tally_id]

    # Create spec_list
    spec_list = []
    for f in selectedTally.filters:
        if f.short_name == 'Mesh':
            mesh_filter = f
            continue
        elif f.short_name in ['Energy', 'Energyout']:
            index = self.filterBoxes[f.short_name].current()
            ebin = f.bins[index]
            spec_list.append((type(f), (ebin,)))
        else:
            index = self.filterBoxes[f.short_name].current()
            spec_list.append((type(f), (index,)))

    dims = (self.nx, self.ny, self.nz)

    text = self.basisBox.get()
    if text == 'xy':
        h_ind = 0
        v_ind = 1
    elif text == 'yz':
        h_ind = 1
        v_ind = 2
    else:
        h_ind = 0
        v_ind = 2

    axial_ind = 3 - (h_ind + v_ind)
    dims = (dims[h_ind], dims[v_ind])

    mesh_dim = len(self.mesh.dimension)
    if mesh_dim == 3:
        mesh_indices = [0,0,0]
    else:
        mesh_indices = [0,0]

    matrix = np.zeros(dims)
    for i in range(dims[0]):
        for j in range(dims[1]):
            if mesh_dim == 3:
                mesh_indices[h_ind] = i + 1
                mesh_indices[v_ind] = j + 1
                mesh_indices[axial_ind] = axial_level
            else:
                mesh_indices[0] = i + 1
                mesh_indices[1] = j + 1
            filters, filter_bins = zip(*spec_list + [
                (type(mesh_filter), (tuple(mesh_indices),))])
            mean = selectedTally.get_values(
                [self.scoreBox.get()], filters, filter_bins)
            stdev = selectedTally.get_values(
                [self.scoreBox.get()], filters, filter_bins,
                value='std_dev')
            if mbvalue == 'Mean':
                matrix[i, j] = mean
            elif mbvalue == 'Absolute uncertainty':
                matrix[i, j] = stdev
            else:
                if mean > 0.:
                    matrix[i, j] = stdev/mean
                else:
                    matrix[i, j] = 0.

    # Clear the figure
    self.fig.clear()

    # Make figure, set up color bar
    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    cax = self.axes.imshow(matrix.transpose(), vmin=0.0, vmax=matrix.max(),
                           interpolation='none', origin='lower')
    self.fig.colorbar(cax)

    self.axes.set_xticks([])
    self.axes.set_yticks([])
    self.axes.set_aspect('equal')

    # Draw canvas
    self.canvas.draw()

def get_file_data(self, filename):
    # Create StatePoint object and read in data
    self.datafile = StatePoint(filename)

    # Find which tallies are mesh tallies
    self.meshTallies = []
    for itally, tally in self.datafile.tallies.items():
        if any([isinstance(f, MeshFilter) for f in tally.filters]):
            self.meshTallies.append(itally)

    if not self.meshTallies:
        messagebox.showerror("Invalid StatePoint File",
                             "File does not contain mesh tallies!")
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('statepoint', nargs='?', help='Statepoint file')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Hide root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# If no filename given as command-line argument, open file dialog
if args.statepoint is None:
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select statepoint file',
                                          initialdir='.')
else:
    filename = args.statepoint

if filename:
    # Check to make sure file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        messagebox.showerror("File not found",
                             "Could not find regular file: " + filename)
        sys.exit(1)

    app = MeshPlotter(root, filename)
    root.deiconify()
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hello Ganiel, you have posted an answer to your own question. Instead, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63209613/edit) your question to add more necessary details for better understanding.

Comment: @Saad Thank you for the correction. Please I did try to correct it by using the edit but I was unsuccessful. Sorry I am new here and I when I tried correcting it I had an error message.